# pass an array to a js file in its declarative shape

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

i want to send a list from a view to a js file.
In the js file, the variable should be displayed exactly like this ['a','b','c']
so that it s considered as an array.
But when i pass the variable, it s interpreted as a whole string.

in my controller:
    List varList=new List();

```
        //Headings();

        variableEntities var = new variableEntities();
        var parametre = var.Variable.Select(p => new { p.Paramètre }).ToList();
        foreach (var p in parametre)
        {
            varList.Add(p.Paramètre);

        }

        string joined = string.Join(",", varList.ToArray());
       // varList=varList.Substring(1,varList.Length - 2);

        ViewData["List"] = joined;
```

in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

List = '@ViewBag.List';
</script> 
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/config.js"></script>
```

in my config.js file, i have this part:

```
config.placeholder_select = {
    placeholders: [List],//I should have exactly this ['a','b','c'] and not a whole string
    format: '[[%placeholder%]]'
}
```

Any idea

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: from view you can send only string. try stroing the values using "," separated and in js you can convert it into array using split(",") function

Comment: @SergeyS i editted my post

Comment: @dharmesh it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was the one given by dharmesh in the comments:

"from view you can send only string. try stroing the values using "," separated and in js you can convert it into array using split(",") function"

Thank you